# Python Mozek optimization - nonlinear constraints

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, scip

I am comparing SCIP and Mozek with a very simple optimization task, but I had a hard time to understand how to code for Mozek when constraints are nonlinear. For example:

```
from pyscipopt import Model    
md = Model()
x = md.addVar('x', lb=0, ub=5, vtype='I')
y = md.addVar('y', lb=0, ub=5, vtype='I')
z = md.addVar('z')
md.setObjective(z, sense='maximize') 
md.addCons(2*x + y <= 8)
md.addCons(x * y == z)
```

Can anyone help with the equivalent code for the example above, using Mozek package in python? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Mosek is for convex problems only.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you for the comments. Given the range of x and y both being positive, may I consider the x*y = z a convex constraint? I couldn't find a conic method in Mozek that matches this type of constraint.

Comment: This is non-convex.  You could use a series of binary variables (instead of integer variables) and linearize the product. Or use a solver like Gurobi.